# Inline math - Space between $\mathcal{A}$ and $\forall$ symbol

Tags: math-mode, spacing

What is the most elegant way to increase space or add space between a char and a `\forall` command? I have this simple expression:

```
$\mathcal{T}[i] \in \mathcal{A} \forall i \in [1, N]$
```

but the result is not what I hope... There is not space between the `A` and the `\forall` symbol. I try to use `\quad` but the space is to much.

Comment: I'd probably use quad but `\;` is less (usually)

Comment: For inline math I'd rather write this as `$\mathcal{T}[i] \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $i \in [1, N]$` as it is much nicer to read. Our local rule is to spell quantors out unless they are vital to what you are writing (say if you are writing the exact definition of what a limit is).

Comment: Why are you writing this like this?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a `\` so the equation would become

```
$\mathcal{T}[i] \in \mathcal{A} \ \forall i \in [1, N]$
```

but that is just personal preference.